# Getting an infinite loop for one function but not for a similar function, trying to validate date input

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop

Trying to create an input validation for a date in format YYYY-MM-DD. I have two methods of doing this.

The first method seems to work, and loops back through to get input each time an error is raised.

The function in the second method is causing an infinite loop, but a nearly identical function in the first method does not.

If I enter a correctly formatted date in the second method, it prints as expected, but for any other input, it creates the infinite loop.

I'm not sure where this is breaking down?

I've looks in a number of Google results, and there are lots of date validations out there, but I haven't found one that explicitly addresses how to loop back around and try again.

I wasn't sure what else to try without essentially just rewriting method one.

```py
import datetime as dt

#METHOD 1 - This is the first method for validating date input, which takes in individual blocks and validates each one individually. 

def get_date(year_prompt, month_prompt, day_prompt):

    #Year Input
    while True:
        try:
            year = int(input(year_prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.\n")
            continue
        if year in range(2000,3000,1):
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, your response must be in YYYY format and later than the year 2000.\n")
            continue

    #Month Input
    while True:
        try:
            month = int(input(month_prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.\n")
            continue
        if month in range(1,13,1):
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, needs to be MM and between 1-12\n")
            continue

    #Day Input
    while True:
        try:
            day = int(input(day_prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.\n")
            continue
        if day in range(1,32,1):
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, needs to be DD and between 1-31\n")
            continue

    #Takes the three inputs and puts them together into a date
    date = dt.datetime(year, month, day)

    #Returns the date      
    return date

#Runs the first method of getting and validating a date.
date = get_date("\nYYYY: ", "\nMM: ", "\nDD: ")

#Prints the validated date.
print("\nThe date you entered is: ", date, "\n")


#METHOD 2 - This is the second method for validating date, which takes in the whole date in one input, and attempts to validate it against the YYYY-MM-DD format.

def input_validation(date):
    while True:
        try:
            dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("\nSorry, this does not appear to be a valid date in format YYYY-MM-DD")
            continue        
    return date

#Prints the validated date. 
print("\nThe date you entered is: ", input_validation(input("Enter a date in format YYYY-MM-DD: ")), "\n")
```

My expected result for the second method, is either a date in format YYYY-MM-DD, or an error message that then asks for the input again.

Comment: but why do you even have the `while True` ? You can easily get rid of it

Comment: but why do you even have the while True ? You can easily get rid of it Check my answer below if it makes sense @DarmokAtPioneer

Comment: But your code only asks for the input once. The function `input_validation` does not ask for input at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the infinite loop `while True`, and return `True` or `False` based on the date being in the correct format

```
def input_validation(date):

    #Flag to check date format
    flag = False
    try:
        #If date is of correct format, set flag to True
        dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        flag = True
    except ValueError:
        print("\nSorry, this does not appear to be a valid date in format YYYY-MM-DD")
    #Return flag
    return flag

print(input_validation('2019-01-31'))
print(input_validation('2019-001-31'))
print(input_validation('2019-01-311'))
```

The output will be

```
True

Sorry, this does not appear to be a valid date in format YYYY-MM-DD
False

Sorry, this does not appear to be a valid date in format YYYY-MM-DD
False
```

You can wrap this function around your `while True` to continue taking input from user

```
while True:
    date_str = input('Enter Date')
    if input_validation(date_str):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Issue I'm having isn't that I can't validate whether the input is a date or not, it's that on method two, if the date is not valid, it's creating an infinite loop instead of allowing the user a second chance to enter a correct date. So, in your example it's returning false, but instead of returning false it needs to ask for the input again as in method one. I suppose I could move the loop outside of the function?

Comment: You can write a loop using this function, which breaks if the `input_validation` returns True else it continues on @DarmokAtPioneer have added an example to the answer, please take a look